Console login coming back after the MFA success
Environment:  Ubuntu 20.04 Terminal Server (CLI) and Ubuntu 22.04 Terminal Server (CLI) and GUI based systems of Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04
I have a custom PAM module service for MFA (Multi Factor Authentication).
I add this PAM module service in /etc/pam.d/login above the @Include common-auth as shown below:
Entries in /etc/pam.d/login file:
> auth     required      tecmfa.so
>  @Include common-auth

When I do login though the Console, I type my username in Login: prompt
and later the password for the Password: prompt.
Doing this will call the MFA, after Finishing the MFA successfully, it is prompting for the Login prompt Login: again.
For trouble shooting the issue, I have collected the logs for auth.log and syslog:
command : sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log /var/log/syslog
==> /var/log/auth.log <==
>     Aug  7 17:18:04 Ubuntu20 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user rpabbathi by (uid=0) Aug  7 17:18:08 Ubuntu20
> TecMFA[1383]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user
> rpabbathi Aug  7 17:18:12 Ubuntu20 systemd-logind[762]: Session c2
> logged out. Waiting for processes to exit. Aug  7 17:18:12 Ubuntu20
> systemd-logind[762]: Removed session c2. Aug  7 17:18:46 Ubuntu20
> sshd[1498]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for rpabbathi from
>     192.168.112.128 port 52494 ssh2 Aug  7 17:18:46 Ubuntu20 sshd[1498]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user rpabbathi
> by (uid=0) Aug  7 17:18:46 Ubuntu20 systemd-logind[762]: New session 4
> of user rpabbathi. Aug  7 17:18:46 Ubuntu20 systemd:
> pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user rpabbathi by
> (uid=0) Aug  7 17:19:42 Ubuntu20 sudo: rpabbathi : TTY=pts/0 ;
> PWD=/home/rpabbathi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -f
> /var/log/auth.log /var/log/syslog Aug  7 17:19:42 Ubuntu20 sudo:
> pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by
> rpabbathi(uid=0)

==> /var/log/syslog <==
> Aug  7 17:18:50 Ubuntu20 dbus-daemon[1515]: [session uid=1002
> pid=1515] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' Aug  7
> 17:18:50 Ubuntu20 systemd[1502]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata
> service. Aug  7 17:18:50 Ubuntu20 systemd[1502]: Started Tracker file
> system data miner. Aug  7 17:18:50 Ubuntu20 systemd[1502]: Reached
> target Main User Target. Aug  7 17:18:51 Ubuntu20 dbus-daemon[1515]:
> [session uid=1002 pid=1515] Successfully activated service
> 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1' Aug  7 17:18:51 Ubuntu20 systemd[1502]:
> Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager. Aug  7
> 17:18:51 Ubuntu20 systemd[1502]: Startup finished in 4.112s. Aug  7
> 17:19:01 Ubuntu20 systemd[1502]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
> Aug  7 17:19:28 Ubuntu20 tracker-store[1622]: OK Aug  7 17:19:28
> Ubuntu20 systemd[1502]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.

Observations:
From the logs I see session being opened and closed in the auth.log
I had added the following
"session required    tecmfa.so" before and after the @Include common-session to see the session is not closed.
Also tested by adding "session required    tecmfa.so" after @Include common-auth also
Nothing worked for me to save the session being closed after successful MFA.
Note:
I have added "authrequiredtecmfa.so" based on this information:
common modules (or configuration files) you might find in /etc/pam.d/:
login: This file controls the authentication process for console logins.
Question:
Do i need to add anything more in the configuration files of /etc/pam.d/, so that session is not closed after the MFA success.
(or)
What should i added in my configuration files of /etc/pam.d/ so that session is not closed after MFA success.
